# AllAuth allowing login from users.email and account_emailaddress tables

Tags: django, django-models, django-allauth

Allauth is allowing me to log in from email addresses in account_emailaddress.email and from user.email. How can I keep these both consistant so it only allows login from one table or another?

Considering updating account_emailaddress.email in views but not sure if thats the best way to go about it.

models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

  def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
    now = timezone.now()
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(
        email=email,
        is_staff=is_staff, 
        is_active=True,
        is_superuser=is_superuser, 
        last_login=now,
        date_joined=now, 
        **extra_fields
    )
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

  def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

  def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    user=self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    secondary_email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=False, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)
```

settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGIN_URL = 'signin'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with

models:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress
from allauth.account.signals import email_confirmed

class CustomUser(models.Model):
    ...
    def add_email_address(self, request, new_email):
        # Add a new email address for the user, and send email confirmation.
        # Old email will remain the primary until the new one is confirmed.
        return EmailAddress.objects.add_email(request, self.user, new_email, confirm=True)

@receiver(email_confirmed)
def update_user_email(sender, request, email_address, **kwargs):
    # Once the email address is confirmed, make new email_address primary.
    # This also sets user.email to the new email address.
    # email_address is an instance of allauth.account.models.EmailAddress
    email_address.set_as_primary()
    # Get rid of old email addresses
    stale_addresses = EmailAddress.objects.filter(
        user=email_address.user).exclude(primary=True).delete()
```

views:

```
def update_user_details(request):
    user = request.user
    new_email = request.POST.get('new_email')
    user.custom_user.add_email_address(request, new_email)
    ...
```